# How to use vuetify image srcset - vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, srcset

I want to use srcset in v-img component in vuetify. I am passing the path from a data attribute.My src attribute is working fine with same syntax but srcset does not works.

Here is the code:

```
<v-img 
  :src="image.original_path" 
  :srcset="image.mobile_path 480w" 
  class="image-masonry mini-cover">
</v-img>
```

If I use it in this way it throws error.
How can i set srcset properly?
Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Try  this =><v-img :src="require(image.original_path') >

Comment: Is your src working?

Comment: Yes, src is working

Answer (score 3):

You have a variable and a raw string in the srcset you need to combine them to form a string. For example:

```
:srcset="`${image.mobile_path} 480w`"
```

or

```
:srcset="image.mobile_path + ' 480w'"
```

So the final version would would look like:

```
<v-img 
  :src="image.original_path" 
  :srcset="`${image.mobile_path} 480w`"
  class="image-masonry mini-cover">
</v-img>
```

More info:
[Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)